# How to create a deployable Qt5 application for OS X

Tags: c++, qt

I have a project GUI in Qt 5.5 with Mac OSX. I was wondering how I would go about creating a deployable file. I looked online and have found nothing on the topic that is understandable.

Meaning that you can just have a file that you can send over email.

Comment: How about compiling it ?

Comment: I meant to put it into an executable file that can run the entire application... Currently I am opening QtEditor and just running "Build", then "Run"

Comment: You should learn how to compile code on the command line. You should learn how to tweak compilation options (notably compiling with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` and later adding `-O2 -mcpu=native` for benchmarking)

Comment: Build and Run creates an executable file. It already does the compilation and linking. You could learn to compile code on the command line, but you need not. All of those settings are available in an IDE.

Comment: The word you are looking for is "deploy". Google "deploy qt5 mac".

Comment: After googling, you should end up here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/osx.html#deploying-applications-on-os-x

Comment: Look at macdeployqt. That should work fine for the usual simple app. If you have more advanced issues, it might not suffice, then come back with more specific questions.

Comment: This link (http://lynxline.com/submiting-to-mac-app-store/) is old and for Qt4 but can give you some help to understand the especialties.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my answer:

In terminal window

cd ~/your_project_folder/
qmake -project
qmake
make

taken from [Compile a Qt project from command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206462/compile-a-qt-project-from-command-line)